# Matching decimal number in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file that has the line:

Time 97.7518 seconds

I want to get the decimal time. Why is the following simple grep command not working?

```
grep -Ei "\d+\.\d+" Nasa-1024-256.txt
```

Comment: Try `grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" Nasa-1024-256.txt`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: or `awk '$1 == "Time" {print $2}' Nasa-1024-256.txt`

Comment: This is also a nice approach. I think awk will suit better for me in future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to need the `-o` option to extract the match, and using the `[0-9]` bracket expression is safer with ERE regex flavor (it is set by the `-E` option):

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" Nasa-1024-256.txt
```